# Typo in Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, paris, schengen-visas

My passport was stamped with Schengen visa on 24th April and is valid till Oct  with stay of 90 days.

I received it via courier today. I live in Bangalore and due to appointment date problem, visa was stamped from Mumbai Consulate.

There is a problem in my Visa . There is a typo in Passport number printed in stamped visa .

The first letter is written as M instead of K. All the numbers are correct .

**M**xxxxxx instead of **K**xxxxxx.

My flight is booked for 30th April and I am arriving there on 1st May. I have only two working days before travel.

Please assist me - what should I do?

This travel also can't be avoided as it is a corporate travel and it's quite important due to certain Project Responsibilities and Client Commitment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try calling the consulate, but I doubt it will help much.  Since time is so short, if I were in your shoes I would first try to postpone or cancel the trip.  If that is not possible, I would

1. Notify my employer of the error and the resulting possibility of being denied entry, and
2. Unless instructed otherwise by my employer, travel anyway and hope nobody notices and that, if they do notice, they recognize that it is a clerical error that should not affect the validity of the visa, and
3. Be prepared to be refused boarding by the airline or to be refused entry by immigration authorities.

Comment: Can I not convince them that , this is a clerical error. I already have traveled once in November and in my previously stamped visa everything was appropriate.

Comment: @user3636634 maybe, maybe not. I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Talked to Counslate in banagalore. They told me to come with my file and passport tomorrow and they will correct it . Thanks Mate :)

Comment: Counslate official cancelled the previously stamped visa and issued a new one , all in just 5 hours :)